# Power Series Representation of (-3x)/(x^2+x-2)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Question: Find a power series representation of the following, $\frac{-3x}{x^2+x-2}$.

My Approach:

1. Break down denominator using partial fraction decomposition as,
   $$ \frac{-1}{x-1} + \frac{-2}{x+2}$$
2. Taking -1 out as,
   $$
   -1\left(\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-(-x/2)}\right)
   $$
3. Expressing it as,
   $$
   -1 \left( \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(-1/2)^nx^n \right)
   $$

Result, Error ==> Wrong Answer

I just recently started learning about series and sequences, can someone please point out any errors in my logic and help answer the question?

Comment: check step 2: if you take $-1$ out, inside brackets you must have $\frac1{x-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x=0$ you should get the same value of $0$ for both, the  fraction and the infinite series. You have the right ideas about the partial fractions. Please check your negative signs  again and fix your error.

Comment: Lower bounds is 0 (n = 0), hope this helps.

Comment: With the partial decomposition, the x is no longer in the numerator. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you get the same result  for x=0 in your series and your original fraction ?

Comment: The left sum gives you $1$; the right sum gives you $(-1/2)^0 x^0 = 1$ as well; the whole expression in parens is therefore $2$. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the square in the denominator 
$(x+0.5)^2-0.25-2$ hence $-2.25\left(1-\frac{(x+0.5)^2}{1.5^2}\right)$ so 
We have 
$\frac{-3x}{-2.25\left(1-\left(\frac{x+0.5}{1.5}\right)^2\right)}$
Use same thing you did